# Magnitude of a Vector in Spherical Coordinates with No Radial Component

Tags: vectors, physics, spherical-coordinates

Logically, it seems like the magnitude of a vector in spherical coordinates should just be the radial component,  but if the vector has a radial component of zero, does that make the magnitude zero?

It seems like this shouldn't be the case, since in physics, we sometimes can have, say, a velocity vector with no radial component. We usually say speed is the magnitude of velocity, but in cases like this, the speed does not seem to be zero. So what is it?

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of a vector whose spherical coordinate "radial" component is zero is... zero.

Consider the path (in $(r, \theta, \phi)$) coordinates 
$$
u(t)= (2t, 0, 0).
$$

At $t = 0$, this passes through the origin.

Its derivative (in spherical polar coordinates again) is 
$$
u'(t) = (2, 0, 0)
$$
At $t = 0$, this derivative is, in spherical coordinates, $(2, 0, 0)$, which is not zero, which reflects the fact that $u$ is a path that travels along a diameter of a sphere at constant speed, so its speed, at any moment, should indeed be nonzero.

Comment: So a path which stays at a constant radius $u(t) = (R_0, \phi(t), \theta(t))$ has a derivative with a magnitude of zero?

Comment: Nope. Let's look at $u(t) = (2, 0, 2t)$; in rectangular coordinates, that's $U(t) = (2 \cos 2t, 2 \sin 2t, 0)$; the derivative is $U'(t) = (-4\sin 2t, 4 \cos 2t, 0)$, which in polar coordinates is $u'(t) = (4, 0, 2t + \frac{\pi}{2})$. You can't just take term-by-term derivatives in polar coordinates. (You **can** do so for a path where only $r$ varies, which is what I did in my example, but that requires proof; I apologize for apparently sweeping that under the rug in my answer.) Why can't you take term-by-term derivatives and expect the right answer?

Comment: Because the change-of-coordinates function is not **linear**, so the chain rule comes into play. See lines 24-32 at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html for details.