# What is the method to find the magnitude of a vector denoted in spherical coordinates?

Tags: vectors, spherical-coordinates

I have read some related posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650383/magnitude-of-a-vector-in-spherical-coordinates-with-no-radial-component) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350342/magnitude-of-a-vector-in-spherical-and-cylindrical-coordinates), but have some confusion after seeing some worked examples in my textbook (Elements of Electromagnetics 7th ed, Sadiku 2018) which seem to disagree with what I understood from those posts.

In one example, there are two vectors $\textbf{A} = 3\textbf{a}_r + 2\textbf{a}_\theta - 6\textbf{a}_\phi$ and $\textbf{B} = 4\textbf{a}_r + 3\textbf{a}_\phi$ denoted in the spherical coordinate system.

By my working, their cross product is $\textbf{A} \times \textbf{B} = 6\textbf{a}_r - 33\textbf{a}_\theta - 8\textbf{a}_\phi$

My confusion lies in finding the magnitude of this vector quantity. Intuitively it seems to me that the magnitude should be $|\textbf{A} \times \textbf{B}| = 6$, the value of the coefficient of $\textbf{a}_r$. Instead, the textbook lists the answer as $|\textbf{A} \times \textbf{B}| = \sqrt{6^2 + (-33)^2 + (-8)^2} = 34.48$.

What is the correct method of finding the magnitude of $|\textbf{A} \times \textbf{B}|$?

Also, is it correct that $|\textbf{A}| = 3$? Or should it be $|\textbf{A}| = \sqrt{3^2 + 2^2 + (-6)^2}=7$?

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to look into what a norm is (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics) for example). But, in these sort of situations (what we call "Euclidean spaces"), one computes the norm of an $N$-dimensional vector $(\xi_1, \xi_2, \dots, \xi_N)$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ as $\sqrt{ \xi^{2}_{1} + \xi^{2}_{2} + \cdots + \xi^{2}_{N} }.$ The reasons for this are connected to the notion of an inner product, which you may also be interested in at some point in the future.

Comment: @TroubleIsBack thanks! A quick follow up, does the notation $|\textbf{A}|$ usually indicate the norm of the vector $\textbf{A}$, or the length of the vector? It seems that varying the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ would change the norm of the vector but not its length.

Comment: The (Euclidean) norm of a vector and its length (in Euclidean spaces, at the very least) coincide, so such a notation is typically appropriate (if you are using a different norm, however, the Euclidean length and the norm may not coincide).

Comment: For your second question, it is related to a property about certain types of transformations of vectors. What you have described is a rotation, and one can show that rotations are examples of "orthogonal" or "unitary" transformations. I prefer the choice "unitary" (in reference to complex vector spaces) because it illuminates the idea of what's going on: unitary transformations preserve (Euclidean) lengths. Think about it this way: how good would a change of coordinates be if it also changed how long things were? Does the size of your car change when you look at it from a different angle? Nope

Comment: Keep in mind that $A = 3a_r + 2a_\theta - 6a_\phi$ doesn't mean that $A$ is pointing at the point $r = 3, \theta = 2, \phi = -6,$ it means that $A$ consists of taking $3$ steps in the "$r$-direction," $2$ in the "$\theta$-direction," and $6$ backwards in the "$\phi$-direction." The spherical unit vectors are quite different from how we use the variables themselves to define points. (also, the "square root of the sum of squares" ends up still working out because these spherical unit vectors are still orthonormal with respect to the Euclidean norm)

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you both for the explanation! Apologies but I've still got one hangup: in the case of the vector $N = -a_z$, its Euclidean norm is $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1$; but in the spherical coordinate system the equivalent vector $N' = a_r + \pi a_\theta$ has Euclidean norm $\sqrt{1^2 + \pi^2 }\neq 1$. What have I missed?

Comment: This kind of feeds back into what I said before, we need to separate the concept of the coordinates from that of our spherical coordinate unit vectors. The issue here is that although $(0, 0, -1)_{xyz} = (1, 0, \pi)_{r\theta\phi},$ it's not true that $-a_z \neq a_r + \pi a_\theta,$ the conversion is more complicated than that. In applications, spherical unit vectors are mainly used to easily describe motion in a rotating frame of reference, so the way the same Cartesian form vector is written in our spherical form depends on where we "start from."

Comment: For instance, if we "start from" $(1, 0, 0),$ note that if we consider the circle we would get by holding $r$ and $\theta$ constant and increase $\phi,$, the tangent line here would be straight down. So, in this sense, going $1$ unit down ($-a_z$) corresponds with going $1$ unit in the "$\phi$-direction." So, at $(1,0,0), -a_z = a_\phi,$ and $|-a_z| = |a_\phi| = 1.$ Does that make sense?

Comment: (pardon me actually, I just realized I was using $\phi$ as the azimuthal angle where you were using it as the polar angle, and vice versa for $\theta.$ just minor convention difference, but you'll have to switch the $\phi$'s and $\theta$'s to make it work your way)

Comment: @StephenDonovan Yes, that makes sense! Thank you!